# Remote desktop without log off the user out

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have windows server 2003 with active directory and my users running on windows xp pro and I would like to use remote desktop without to log them out when I login with my account in other words I would use the PC as same time the user using it both of us can working. I know it's working on windows server 2003
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You can't do that with Windows XP. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade them to a better operating system. Multi user capability was introduced AFTER xp, and still only one user is allowed for a non-server at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done, you can get access to the same desktop using [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) but that will not be practical for simultaneous use, only for troubleshooting, etc.